# Keyboard button randomly pressed in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

I'm having problem with my keyboard. Whenever I type something, 0 is also pressed. While booting, the screen is filled with "^[[2~". Sometime it causes boot loop. How can I fix that?

Comment: Would try another keyboard to see if problem with keyboard or Ubuntu.  Thinking dirt or struck key.  Google will have quite a few instructions on cleaning/fixing your keyboard, be specific with laptop/keyboard make and model.

Comment: I fixed that. Thank you for suggestion. Actually a key was stuck in the builtin keyboard of my laptop.